# how to get the exit status of the first command in a pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exit-code

I made a simple script:

```
$ more test.bash
#!/bin/bash
echo test
exit 1
```

When I run the script , the exit status should be **1**

```
$ /tmp/test.bash
echo $?
1
```

But when I run this as the following

```
/tmp/test.bash | tr -d '\r' 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
echo $?
0
```

The exit status is **0**, (not as expected **1**)

It seems that the exit status comes from tr command.
But I what I want is to get the exit status from the script - test.bash.

What do I need to add/change in my syntax in order to get the right exit status from the script, and not from the command after the pipe line?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `PIPESTATUS` array:

```
$ ls foo | cat
ls: foo: No such file or directory
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
2 0
```

Note: `PIPESTATUS` is a bashism (i.e. not POSIX).

Comment: VERY VERY NICE AND NEW FOR ME !   ( +1 for you )

Comment: It was a pleasure helping out a fellow human being :-)

Comment: VOTE FOR THE GREAT ANSWER

Comment: Alternative: You can check whether _all_ commands exited with 0 by initializing with `set -o pipefail`